# Combine two vertex color layers?

Tags: vertex-colors

This one is still version 2.79. I would like to combine the two vertex color layers into one. These are what the layers look like:

[image]

[image]

I want to add them onto each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this is the best way, but you could try using the Data Transfer modifier (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/modifiers/modify/data_transfer.html?highlight=vertex%20color).
Note that I only tried this on 2.83, but according to the documentation you should be able to do this in 2.79.

Say that you have two vertex color layers named `color A` and `color B`

1. Duplicate your object
2. On the duplicated object remove `color A` and rename `color B` to `color A`
3. On the duplicated object add Data Transfer modifier.
   Set `target` to original object.
   Check `Face Corner Data` with `Topology` method.
   Select `VCol` and select `color A` layer.
   Set `Mix Method` to `Add`

My test: Leftmost sphere with `color A` layer; Middle spehere with `color B` layer; Rightmost sphere with added layers.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I selected "multiply" instead of "add", but it got me the exact results that I wanted :)

Comment: @NiklasWobbel if this has answered your question consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.79 this is simple:

1. Set Bake Mode to Full Render
2. Set Bake to Vertex Colors
3. In Render tab, disable "Textures" in the Shading category
4. Make sure you have the camera icon set on your target (merged) vcols layer
5. Do Bake